# New instance starting on ~every request for Google App Engine service

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, memory-leaks

I have a service build with Java & Spring Boot, running on Google App Engine.
On basically every request, I started getting the same errors about the memory limit being reached, and a new process starting up.

Sometimes the request succeeds and sometimes it fails. But either way it takes a very long time.

```
Exceeded soft memory limit of 256 MiB with 276 MiB after servicing 1 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
```

```
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

```
After handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
```

This seemed to start all of a sudden, and to try to isolate the issue, I literally removed all my code and I'm just returning a 200 status from my server. Even with the barebones implementation of my controller, I get this memory issue. Wondering if there are ways to debug or something in my app engine that could be causing an issue?

I don't think I need more memory for my service as this is happening on just a single request with no logic.

Comment: `256` MiB might not be enough for a spring boot application, have you tried increasing the memory limit as suggested in the error message?

Comment: I just tried F2 and that worked. Curious if there's any documentation you can recommend on spring boot's memory usage? I'm new to spring boot and didn't expect very simple functionality to take that much memory.

Comment: that depends on what dependencies your application have, we have spring boot apps that requires 1GB of RAM and some even 2GB